# font in list of formulas wrong

Tags: fonts

My whole document is in Palatino font (I think), only the list of formulas has a serif font. I want everything to be uniform.
Here is the example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openright]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsche Trennmuster
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath} % Schriftart Palatino & passende Mathe-Schrift
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Einstellung Schriftkodierung

\newcounter{myequation}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\themyequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{myequation}}
\newcommand{\myequation}[1]{\refstepcounter{myequation}\label{#1}\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\themyequation}\hspace{0.5em}$\displaystyle \texttt{#1}$}}

\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{Formelverzeichnis}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2em} 

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
I = {\frac {U}{R}}
\myequation{Ohm'sches Gesetz}
\end{align}

\newpage
\listofmyequations 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Formelverzeichnis}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "only the list of formulas has a serif font" -- Actually, it has a **monospaced** (aka typewriter) font. This property, in turn, is caused by the difficult-to-comprehend instruction `$\displaystyle \texttt{#1}$`. Do replace this instruction, subito, with `#1`.

Comment: By the way, in order to make your code compilable, it's necessary to load the `tocloft` package.

Comment: Off-topic: If you want Palatino (clone) text and math fonts, you need to load the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages, *not* the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages. (The latter two packages provide Times Roman (clone) fonts.)